# Using google drive(or any cloud server) as storage database for android app

Tags: android

I am thinking of making an android app with several users logging into a discussion forum(something like the whatsapp group chat or maybe facebook group chat) and i want to save all data in google drive(or any other server). Please Can anyone tell me how to do it. Any link or and documentation or help through any reply. I am pretty new to android app development and will be eagerly waiting for a reply.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Not tried anything new yet. Asking about how it can be done based on which i will do some net work.